# Google Maps for EE Different on Front End to Back End

Tags: plugin, google-maps-for-ee

Does anyone know if there has been changes to Google's Map API or some other things that would cause previously working Google Maps for EE plugin maps to being plotting/viewing correctly in the control panel (field type) but not on the front end.

No changes have been made to these installs since the beginning of the year.

**EXAMPLE ONE**
Maps now have multiple locations points (should only have one) and no longer centre
EE 2.5.3
GMforEE 3.1.0
http://bit.ly/13LJq9Z (click the 'view' icon to review details and map)

**EXAMPLE TWO**
Maps now have multiple locations points (should only have one)
EE 2.5.5
GMforEE 3.2.1
http://bit.ly/1d5ztHh

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post an example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that after following Justin's instructions in:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/google-maps/viewthread/10492

And adding geocode="false" to exp:gmap:marker the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answers can be found in your javascript - take a closer look, is there extra code on the front end you're loading in - or is it possible that the API is connecting to some default map you've got on Google?

You've got what seems to be extra js code regarding your map centering and zoom - and if you look closely at the code that draws the markers - it's loading the same locations on each site you linked to (see marker index 3 and 4). That seems to suggest you've either got some default/example code in there somewhere, or your maps are being tied to something else?

Comment: Here is a thread outlining a possible/cause solution this problems. Lots of people had this happen to them as a result of the Google Maps API changes. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/google-maps/viewthread/10492